# Ubuntu system font too small

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

After a reboot my Ubuntu system font has gone very small.  This includes window headers, windows and terminal.

Any ideas what has caused this and how I can resolve it?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu (not U**n**buntu, btw.)? Can you include a screenshot, please?

Comment: 14.04, I'd say the font size is 14px

Comment: I don't use Ubuntu, but typically, that setting is under Fonts in the system settings.

Comment: I am having this problem again on 20.04 and I have to use the "large text" trick to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

To solve this problem, go to Applications->Settings->Appearance then goto DPI and uncheck or turn off "Custom DPI setting". Evidently, something causes that to activate during a [faulty] update.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same problem on my machine.

I went into Universal Access in system settings and switched "Large Text" on, then back off. After turning it off, the text went back to it's normal size and all was well.

Comment: This answer is a repeat of the information in Erik's answer.  The only value it adds is to confirm that another solution worked, so it isn't really an answer.  This kind of information can be posted as a comment when you accumulate a little more rep.

Comment: @fixer1234 no, actually, this answer is exactly what I've been forced to do on ubuntu 20.04 after some weird update... It is not equal to erik's answer because it says "switched 'Large Text' on, then back off", and he doesnt say that! What he says here is a USEFUL TRICK on a buggy feature. So again, we have to turn it on (large text) and revert it to it's original/default state (normal text = OFF), and this is a quite useful trick because we should not be required to do that, never!

Comment: but I am using this now: https://askubuntu.com/a/1269402/46437

Answer (score 0):

You can try Gnome Tweak Tool:

https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-tweak-tool/

It's kinda buggy but gets the job done.

There's also an option called "Large Text" in `System Settings > Universal Access` .

Answer (score 0):

Unity Tweak Tool, in the Ubuntu App Store.  I know, it really should be part of the base install.

See this https://askubuntu.com/a/59920/201083

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are referring to small size of everything including cursor, in that case following worked for me!!!
Go to System Settings -> Display.
Change the resolution according to your choice.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, and all I had to do was go to the unity tweak tool and change the "text scaling factor" in the fonts setting.